# How to choose dimensionality of the Dense layer in LSTM?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I have a task of multi-label text classification. My dataset has 1369 classes:

```
# data shape
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
print(Y_train.shape)
print(Y_test.shape)
(54629, 500)
(23413, 500)
(54629, 1369)
(23413, 1369)
```

For this task, I've decided to use LSTM NN with the next parameters:

```
# define model
maxlen = 400
inp = Input(shape=(maxlen, ))
embed_size = 128
x = Embedding(max_features, embed_size)(inp)
x = LSTM(60, return_sequences=True,name='lstm_layer')(x)
x = GlobalMaxPool1D()(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = Dense(2000, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = Dense(1369, activation="sigmoid")(x)
model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=x)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy']
batch_size = 32
epochs = 2
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.1)
```

**Question**: Are there any scientific methods for determining `Dense` and `LSTM` dimensionality (in my example, `LSTM dimension=60`, `I Dense dimension=2000`, and `II Dense dimension=1369`)?

If there are no scientific methods, maybe there are some heuristics or tips on how to do this with data with similar dimension.

I randomly chose these parameters. I would like to improve the accuracy of the model and correctly approach to solving similar problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very broad and difficult question, because these parameters depend completely on the complexity of your dataset. There is (currently) no "scientific method" to determine these parameters. The best solution is to apply a form of [hyperparameter optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization).

See [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/3156/how-to-select-number-of-hidden-layers-and-number-of-memory-cells-in-lstm) similar post for more answers.